# Bounded stack of integers C++

Tags: c++

Hey, just doing some revision for upcoming exams and i'm looking at a past paper.

I'm asked to write the class implementation for this:

```
class Stack
{
    public:
        Stack(int n=1);
        int pop();
        void push(int);
        int isEmpty();
        int isFull();
        ˜Stack();
    private:
        int top; // index of element at top of stack
        int size; // maximum number of elements storable
        int * cell; // pointer to elements stored in stack
};
```

I understand the theory of stacks and i know what the methods have to do, the bit that confuses me is where are the integers that are passed to the stack stored, and how is this done? Maybe im missing something realy simple but im stumped?

Comment: `int * cell; // pointer to elements stored in stack` -- anything unclear about this comment? It's in a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: they're store in cell, which is a pointer to integer, and u can use it to point to an array of integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't have named it that, or likely implemented it in this fashion, but the `int * cell` is where your items go.  I assume they want you to initialize it to an array of `size` when the stack is instantiated.

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess that your `int * cell` is the clue, it is a pointer into an array, so you'd initialize it as such `int * cell = new int[size];`

Now you can use `cell` as an index into your dynamic array.

Answer (score 0):

The integers are stored on the heap, and the 'bottom' element is stored at

```
Stack s(5);
s.cell[0];
```

The second at

```
s.cell[1];
```

and so on.